# Default Value for Datetime column in Entity Framework(ET)

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

Can anyone tell me, how to use the default values from Entity Framework for a datetime column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF designer doesn't have any useful support for configuring default values for a data time. The best way is to initialize default values in constructor of your entity. Each entity is partial class so you can create your own partial part and use:

```
public partial class YourEntity
{
    public YourEntity()
    {
        YourDateProperty = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

The same is valid for code only mapping but in such case you don't need partial part because you can define constructor directly in your manually created entity class.

Comment: If using EF 4.1 code first, the entity does not need to be partial.

Comment: @olivehour: Yes, I mentioned it in the last sentese.

Answer (score 0):

Consider specifying default value in database (column property).

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to use the current time as the default datetime value you can use the `TimeStamp` attribute in the namespace `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` to have .NET create a non-nullable Timestamp column in the database table that your entity represents.

```
[Timestamp]
public Byte[] TimeStamp { get; set; }
```

Code first allows only one Timestamp property per entity.